# Resetting score in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, reset, points

I am creating a "dice spinner" game by using Flash action script 3, The rules are if the player rolls a 7 or 11 on first throw then they win but if the user rolls a 2,3 or 12 on the first throw then they lose. If the first throw is 4,5,6,8,9 or 10 then that sum becomes the point and that user has to make a point by rolling again until they make the point (they win) or they throw a 7 (they lose)

I have succesfully created the functions for it to spin, generate a random between 1-6 on each "dice" and to add the points up from total but my problem is if the user wins or lose. I can't figure out on how to reset the points back to zero when the user rerolls from last attempt

The code is blow.

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

spinner_mc.stop();
spinner2_mc.stop();

roll_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, startspin);
stop_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, stopspin);
spinner_mc.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, spin);
spinner2_mc.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, spin)

var spinning = false

function spin(evt){
    if(spinning){
        spinner_mc.rotation += 5
        spinner2_mc.rotation += 5
    }
} //end spin function

function startspin(mEvt:MouseEvent){
    spinning = true

} //end startspin function

var points:int = 0;
function stopspin (mEvt){
    if (spinning){
        spinning = false
        var nextVal = newVal()
        var nextVal2 = newVal2()
        var addPoints = nextVal + nextVal2
        points += nextVal + nextVal2
        spinner_mc.gotoAndStop(nextVal)
        spinner_mc.rotation = 0
        spinner2_mc.gotoAndStop(nextVal2)
        spinner2_mc.rotation = 0
        value_txt.text = "point = " + points + ", new value " + addPoints
    }
    if ((points == 0) && (addPoints == 7) || (addPoints == 11))
    {
        info_txt.text = "You win!! You rolled a 7 or 11 on first throw!"

    }
    if ((points == 0) && (addPoints == 2) || (addPoints == 3) || (addPoints == 12))
    {
        info_txt.text ="You lose! You rolled a 2, 3 or 12 on first throw!"
    }

} // end stopspin function

function newVal(){
    var temp:int;
    temp = Math.random() * 6 + 1;
    return temp;
}

function newVal2(){
    var temp:int
    temp = Math.random() * 6 + 1;
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: I don't get the loss/win condition if not the first turn. What should the player roll to win? What should the sum be?

Comment: If it is the first “throw” and the sum is 7 or 11, the user wins.


If it is the first throw and the sum is 2, 3 or 12, the user loses.



If on the first throw, the sum is 4,5,6,8,9, or 10, then that sum becomes the “point” and the user then has to “make” that point on their next throw. In order to make the point, the user has to throw the same sum. If not, the user continues to throw until they make the point (they win) or they throw a 7 (they lose)

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for points and `addPoints` *before* you add points to the player, while your code has check for `points` outside the `if (spinning)` block. This makes your checks go awry even if `points` is yet zero. So, you first get the spin values, then check, then assign values.

```
function stopspin(evt:MouseEvent):void {
    if (!spinning) return; // this is shorter than wrapping the entire function
    // body into a single "if (spinning)" block. If we don't spin, get out
    spinning=false;
    var nextVal1:int=newVal();
    var nextVal2:int=newVal(); // no need of two functions doing the same :)
    var addPoints:int=nextVal1+nextVal2;
    spinner_mc.gotoAndStop(nextVal1);
    spinner_mc.rotation = 0;
    spinner2_mc.gotoAndStop(nextVal2);
    spinner2_mc.rotation = 0; // give values to spinners
    // now check phase
    if (points==0) {
        // this means first throw.
        if ((addPoints==7) || (addPoints==11)) {
            // player wins, insert win code
        } else if((addPoints==2)||(addPoints==3)||(addPoints==12)) {
            // player loses, insert lose code
        } else {
            points=addPoints; // otherwise making the player do second throw
            // add other code, say inform the player that he has to throw again
        }
    } else {
        // not a first throw. We have the "point" in "points" variable right now
        if (addPoints==points) {
            // player wins with second throw, add win code
            points=0; // okay, back to first throw
        } else if (addPoints==7) {
            // player loses second throw, add relevant code
            points=0; // again, back to first throw
        } else {
            // else no match, oh well.
        }
    }
}
```

Also, you should know better how to use event listeners if you want several objects to listen with a single function (in your case, `spin`). See, right now you have your `spin` function to update both spinners, and you have it being called twice per frame, so your spinners are spinning at twice the desired speed. You can get the actively listening movie clip using the `Event` class object passed into the listener, you need to get its `target` property. So, your listener can be rewritten like this:

```
function spin(evt:Event):void {
    var mc:DisplayObject=evt.target; // the object that's listening
    mc.rotation+=5; // now turn it.
}
```

And last, please place semicolons at the end of each line. Even if AS3 compiler does not strictly require this, it can save you from some really weird mistakes.